# Bash - Rename media files. Remove special characters from filenames. Goal is Filename=Title.filetype

Tags: linux, bash, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I am playing around to test my acquired bits of ideas gathered from asking here and browsing the internet to rename some media files on a directory. I have

```
printf "%s\n" *
01 - Concrete Jungle.flac
01. Easy.flac
03 - Last Goodbye.flac
05 - Movement in the Light.flac
05-rival_sons-feral_roots.flac
05. Songbird.flac
06 - The First Taste.flac
06. Led Zeppelin - Kashmir.flac
12 Crying Like A Church On Monday.flac
12.-The Way You Make Me Feel.flac
14. Blur - Tender (Zoë Ball XFM Session).flac
20. He Ain't Heavy, He's My Brother.flac
All By Myself - AnythingOldSchool.flac
rename.txt
```

How can I rename them via commandline so that I will have

```
$ ls
Concrete Jungle.flac
Easy.flac
Last Goodbye.flac
Movement in the Light.flac
Feral Roots.flac
Songbird.flac
The First Taste.flac
Kashmir.flac
Crying Like A Church On Monday.flac
The Way You Make Me Feel.flac
Tender.flac
He Ain't Heavy, He's My Brother.flac
All By Myself.flac
```

I've tried copying the filenames to rename.txt and play around piped commands such as

```
cat rename.txt | tr -d '0-9\\' | tr '.' ' ' | sed 's/ \([^ ]*\)$/.\1/'
```

to see what I've got and I'm liking it so far but I am running out of ideas and I'm wondering how can I rename the actual files.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any deterministic pattern for cleaning your filenames; for example `Led Zeppelin - Kashmir` should yield `Kasmir` while `All By Myself - AnythingOldSchool` should yield `All by Myself`. How is a pure text-processing program supposed to know which side of the dash it needs to keep?

Comment: @Fravadona yeah I understand what you mean. sorry I have no better idea.

Comment: Be careful you don't rename "25 or 6 to 4.flac" to "or 6 to 4.flac".

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @jmk "25" is part of the title of the [song by Chicago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8A3HZvGN0qs), not a junk prefix. Similarly, ["99 Red Balloons" by Nena](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiwgOWo7mDc), etc

Comment: @GordonDavisson sure.

Answer (score 2):

**is that what you need?**

```
$ cat sample.txt
01 - Concrete Jungle.flac
01. Easy.flac
03 - Last Goodbye.flac
05 - Movement in the Light.flac
05-rival_sons-feral_roots.flac
05. Songbird.flac
06 - The First Taste.flac
06. Led Zeppelin - Kashmir.flac
12 Crying Like A Church On Monday.flac
12.-The Way You Make Me Feel.flac
14. Blur - Tender (Zoë Ball XFM Session).flac
20. He Ain't Heavy, He's My Brother.flac
All By Myself - AnythingOldSchool.flac

$ sed 's/^[^[:alpha:]]*//' sample.txt
Concrete Jungle.flac
Easy.flac
Last Goodbye.flac
Movement in the Light.flac
rival_sons-feral_roots.flac
Songbird.flac
The First Taste.flac
Led Zeppelin - Kashmir.flac
Crying Like A Church On Monday.flac
The Way You Make Me Feel.flac
Blur - Tender (Zoë Ball XFM Session).flac
He Ain't Heavy, He's My Brother.flac
All By Myself - AnythingOldSchool.flac
```

**Let's do a renaming experiment - create two scripts**

1. create the files from sample.txt by script.sh

   ```
    set -e
    in="${1:-sample.txt}"
    [ ! -f "$in" ] && { echo "$0 - File $in not found."; exit 1; }
    while IFS= read -r file

    do

       echo "Working on $file ..."

       touch "$file"

    done < "${in}"
   ```
2. rename files by script2.sh:

   ```
    for filename in *; do

    newFilename=$(sed 's/^[^[:alpha:]]*//' <<< "$filename")

    mv "$filename" "$newFilename";

    done
   ```

**then try them in the terminal**

```
$ ./script.sh
$ ls

01 - Concrete Jungle.flac                      06 - The First Taste.flac                      All By Myself - AnythingOldSchool.flac
01. Easy.flac                                  06. Led Zeppelin - Kashmir.flac                sample.txt
03 - Last Goodbye.flac                         12 Crying Like A Church On Monday.flac         script.sh
05 - Movement in the Light.flac                12.-The Way You Make Me Feel.flac              script1.sh
05-rival_sons-feral_roots.flac                 14. Blur - Tender (Zoë Ball XFM Session).flac
05. Songbird.flac                              20. He Ain't Heavy, He's My Brother.flac

$ ./script1.sh

$ ls -al

total 24
drwxr-xr-x  18 yao-nienyang  staff  576  5 21 19:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 yao-nienyang  staff  896  5 21 19:13 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 All By Myself - AnythingOldSchool.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Blur - Tender (Zoë Ball XFM Session).flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Concrete Jungle.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Crying Like A Church On Monday.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Easy.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 He Ain't Heavy, He's My Brother.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Last Goodbye.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Led Zeppelin - Kashmir.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Movement in the Light.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 Songbird.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 The First Taste.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 The Way You Make Me Feel.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff    0  5 21 19:13 rival_sons-feral_roots.flac
-rw-r--r--   1 yao-nienyang  staff  402  5 21 19:13 sample.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 yao-nienyang  staff  386  5 21 19:13 script.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 yao-nienyang  staff  213  5 21 19:13 script1.sh
```

Comment: Hey this is close to what I really want to achieve but I can settle with this.

Comment: How can I use this to rename the actual files?

Comment: @jmk: Use Perl's standalone `rename` command: `rename 's/^[^[:alpha:]]*//' *.flac`

Comment: @jmk I've updated my answer for one of the solutions.

Comment: @paulyang0125 I will work on your updated answers. The first script uses while loop and the second for loop right? I am watching video tuts on them now. I hope I can comprehend them easily.

Comment: @jmk my answer is just one of many solutions. I believe you can figure it out and work out your solution. cheer!

Comment: @paulyang0125 you're very kind I keep you posted. cheers!